# Godaddy database storage not lowering when content is deleted

Tags: mysql, godaddy-api

My site is connected to a GoDaddy MySQL database. The database is only 1 gigabyte, and I was almost at the max, so I started to delete some pictures from it using some MySQL commands.

But, when I went back and checked how much space I had now, It was the same as before I deleted some content. Does Godaddy take a long time to refresh it's databases or do MySQL delete commands not work on GoDaddy?

Comment: call go daddy tech support. You are dealing with site data. Don't delete to create space. Sometimes, there are log files generated. You may not be able to clear them.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

It's doubtful anyone here can truly help unless they work for GoDaddy.

But when you say you deleted pictures from your mySQL database... are you really sure the pictures were stored in the database? I suspect more likely they are stored on disk and there is simply a file path stored in the database. Deleting such records would make a minuscule impact on the size of a 1GB database.

If you have access to the information schema, try running the following query

```
SELECT `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME`, `DATA_LENGTH`, `INDEX_LENGTH`
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES`
ORDER BY `DATA_LENGTH`+`INDEX_LENGTH` DESC
```

That should give you some clues around where the trouble is happening, and at least indicate where you should start trimming data